# Getting real data type using ODBC, Data is converted to higher precision

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, double, real-datatype

I have a table having real datatype column in sql server.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_1(f_int int, f_string nchar(10), f_real real); 
INSERT INTO Table_1 (f_int, f_string, f_real) VALUES (42000000, 'myString2', 40003.16);
```

when i execute `select f_real from Table_1;` using ODBC API(From c++ application)
I get value 40003.160156250000 instead of 40003.16

I have binded the result column like below.

```
struct ColValInfo
{
    ColValInfo(){
        pValue = NULL;
    }
    SQLPOINTER pValue;
    SQLINTEGER StrLen_or_Ind;
};
ColValInfo* m_pColValInfo;
m_pColValInfo = new ColValInfo[numColumns];
m_pColValInfo[0].pValue = (SQLPOINTER) new char[50];
SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_DOUBLE, m_pColValInfo[0].pValue,
                siz, &(m_pColValInfo[0].StrLen_or_Ind));
```

Note : SQLPOINTER is a typedef of void *  and SQLINTEGER is typedef of long.
I am getting data by doing below

```
double data = *(double *)m_pColValInfo[0].pValue;
```

I am using odbc driver 13 for communicating with database. As driver takes care of converting data from sql type to native type which is specified in SQLBindCol ODBC call, i want to know how i am getting 40003.160156250000 when i have 40003.16 in my database.
I have changed precision and scale of the data base column to decimal(16,2), to see if that makes any difference, i see no difference it makes.

[image]

Could some please let me know where the conversion is going wrong.

Comment: I'm not a c++ developer, but I had a google anyway. This seems to be an issue/feature with converting the SQL datatype `float`/`real` to C++'s `SQL_C_DOUBLE`. `DOUBLE` is more like `decimal`/`numeric`. This can be shown with the SQL statement `SELECT CONVERT(decimal(32,16),CONVERT(real,40003.16));`, which also returns `40003.1601562500000000`. Have you tried using `SQL_C_FLOAT`? (Note I haven't posted this as an answer as I don't use C++ at all, and I therefore can't test, just relying on a bit of Googling and past questions on SO. tehrefore, I don't know that this is indeed the answer.)

Comment: Are you also still using `double data = *(double *)m_pColValInfo[0].pValue;`? That's still a `double`. [C Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/c-data-types?view=sql-server-2017) says you should use `SQLREAL` for your ODBC datatype and `float` for your C datatype. if you still have `double` in your above code, what happens when you use `float` instead? I.e. `float data = *(float*)m_pColValInfo[0].pValue;`

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. when i do the above i get 40003.1602
where as my database has 40003.16